# Surface 3 Issues - Black Screen After Boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2

I am sure this question has been asked many times, but I have not been able to find an answer. I am trying to install from a usb and I always get passed the purple screen with the Ubuntu logo, and then it stops loading and sends me to a solid black screen. I can tell that the back light is on, but nothing else is happening. I have turned off the safe installer or whatever it is called on Win 10, so that shouldn't be an issue. I have spent hours going in to the grub and changing things hoping it will work, but it never does. Hopefully you guys can help, thanks.

Comment: Nobody here? I'm suffering from the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04 on Surface 3.